# Python Beginner: Passing Selenium WebElement Object to PHP

Tags: php, python, selenium, automation

I'm interested in scrapping data from a website, and pass the data for use it in PHP. I have had a look around, and the best suggestion I have been able to find is to first serialise the Python data and then pass it along.

The issue I have is that I'm unsure how to serialise the Python data.

I'm using Selenium, and I have the following code.

```
test = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("table#resultstable td")
```

I can see the data I want to use by running the variable through a loop and printing it.

```
for val in test:
    print(val.text)
```

However when I try to serialise the object, I receive the following error:

```
json.dumps(test)
....
TypeError: Object of type 'WebElement' is not JSON serializable!
```

I Hope somebody can point me in the right direction, I'm happy in PHP but I have only begun to look Python recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON the data format is limited in what it can store (numbers, strings, booleans, and then arrays or maps (what python calls dictionaries) of these elements (or other arrays or maps which at some point end in one of those formats).  json the python library for manipulating json data can therefore only dump to a json string something that fits those rules.  In your case, I'd suggest as a simple starting point:

`columns = [val.text for val in test] # convert to a list of strings, where each string is the td.text`

`json.dumps(columns)` should then give you something useful

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very good starting point. Converting the element text to strings and having them in a list is exactly what I was looking to do, but was unsure of the Python syntax to achieve this. I'll work on this from here.